# Jetpack Compose - LazyColumn makes an infinite number of recompositions

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I want to display a list of items using `LazyColumn`. I wrote the needed code but when I ran the app I observed that the UI is very laggy. I put some `Logs` to find out where the problem may be and I discovered that the `LazyColumn` inifinitely recomposes the items. I replaced the `LazyColumn` with a `Column` with scrollable modifier and the problem was gone in this case. But I don't know why `LazyColumn` behaves like it did.

The list is this:

```
var rides = mutableStateListOf<Ride>(Ride(...), Ride(...))
```

A list item is like this:

```
@Stable
@Entity(tableName = "ride_table")
data class Ride(
    var img: Bitmap? = null,
    var path: List<List<LatLng>>? = null,
    var cities: List<String>? = null,
    var timeStarted: Long = 0L,
    var timeEnded: Long = 0L,
    var avgSpeedInKmh: Float = 0f,
    var maxSpeedInKmh: Float = 0f,
    var distanceInMeters: Float = 0f,
    var totalTimeInSeconds: Long = 0L,
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Long = 0L
) {
    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
        if(other == null)
            return false
        if(other is Ride) {
            return id == other.id
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

The list composable:

```
@Composable
fun Rides(rides: List<Ride>) {
    Log.d("RECOMPOSE", "1")
    LazyColumn {
        items(rides) { ride ->
            Log.d("RECOMPOSE", "2")
            RideDetails(ride)
        }
    }
    /*Column(modifier = Modifier.verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())) {
        rides.forEach { ride ->
            Log.d("RECOMPOSE", "2")
            RideDetails(ride)
        }
    }*/
}
```

RideDetails:

```
@Composable
fun RideDetails(ride: Ride) {
    Log.d("RECOMPOSE", "3`")
    Text(text = "ride ${ride}")
}
```

`Log Recompose 2` gets called non stop in the case of `LazyColumn`. If I switch to `Column` this doesn't happen and the number of `Log` calls is the expected one. What am I doing wrong using `LazyColumn`?

**UPDATE** (The below `Column` gets called inside the `setContent` that lies in `onCreateView`)

```
Column {

    val cities = rideViewModel.cities
    val filterCities = rideViewModel.filterCities
        
    val rides = rideViewModel.rides

    TopBar {
        ...
    }

    Chips(cities, filterCities)

    Log.d("RECOMPOSE", "RECOMPOSE INSIDE SCREEN")

    Rides(rides)
}
```

Comment: is `rides` declared inside view model or just inside composable?

Comment: @PhilipDukhov It is in a `ViewModel`. And I have a `Composable` that has `var rides = viewModel.rides` and right after it calls  `Rides(rides)`.

Comment: many things can trigger recomposition, I can't see the problem in the code you've posted, my first guess was `rides`, but as it's in the view model, it can't behave like this. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @PhilipDukhov  tried making one. The problem doesn't persist there. Going back to the big app, I played with the values of the Ride items (I turned SOME float values into zeroes and made others null - not all of them). The infinite recompositions stopped. But when I scroll very slowly through the LazyColumn, they start again. I discarded all these changes and I downgraded the compose version. The infinite recompositions stopped. But the scroll thing is still there. I don't think it's worth the headache. I'll use the XML Recyclerview.

Comment: I read some posts from some months ago that talked about very laggy LazyColumn. I think they have the same problem as I do.

Comment: I've been using it for half a year now, it may not be as perfectly performant as `RecyclerView`, but I haven't encountered any severe lags as you describe. You may be doing something wrong without realizing it, or encountering an error. In the first case, by reducing the example to minimally reproducible, you can discover the problem by yourself or show it to me; in the second case, it would be very useful to report it so that it can be fixed. But it's up to you, I understand that you may not have enough time to experiment.

Comment: @PhilipDukhov For now I'll switch to RecylerView but I'll try to recreate the problem again in the next days. Maybe it got something to do with the content of the list passed to the LazyColumn, which would be so weird. But from my experiments that seems to be one factor.

Answer (score 0):

I've just encountered the same problem with a slightly modified code from the [Thinking in Compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/mental-model#parallel) Article. In my opinion this is a minimal reproducible as requested by @Philip Dukhov

It gets passed a tiny list of 30 items in this case but the counter goes up endlessly. The LazyColumn displays only the 30 items passed though.

I would be very thankful for an explanation.

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            SimpleAnimationsTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colors.background
                ) {
                    var testList = listOf<String>()
                    for(i in 1..30) testList += "Test #$i"
                    ListWithoutBug(myList = testList)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun ListWithoutBug(myList: List<String>) { // apparently with bug
    val items = remember { mutableStateOf<Int>(0) }

    Row(horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween) {
        LazyColumn{
            items(myList) { item ->
                Text("Item: $item")
                items.value++
            }
        }
        Text("Count: ${items.value}")
    }
}
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ragqU.png)

Comment: It's not that simple. You update `items` on each recomposition. But the way you use items, by displaying it in the `Text` composable, also triggers recompositions of the parent, `Row`. This may imply to amount of recompisitions for `LazyRow`. So this would be not the best option to count recompositions.

Comment: Yeah that kinda makes sense, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in my XML file.

It was like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbarWrapper"
        ...
     />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_title"
        ...
    />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_subtitle"
      ...
    />

    <androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView
        android:id="@+id/compose_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:paddingTop="12dp"
        android:paddingBottom="12dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/btn_ok"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_subtitle" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_ok"
        ...
    />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

To resolve the recompositions of my LazyColumn, I left only the ComposeView on the XML and converted the rest to Composes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/compose_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```